# Service named failed to start

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, centos6, dns-zone

Service named (DNS/Bind) is failing to start. What am I doing wrong? I think it has to do with my 155.100.198.in-addr.arpa file, but I can't see my error.

I am getting the following errors:

```
zone 155.100.198.in-addr.arpa/IN: has no NS records
zone 155.100.198.in-addr.arpa/IN: not loaded due to errors.
_default/155.100.198.in-addr.arpa/IN: bad zone
```

Running on Centos 6 using a Plesk control panel. 
The following files are in Director: /var/named/
Except for named.conf, which is under: /var/named/chroot/etc/

**In my named.conf file my call to zones are:**

```
zone "benmorgancreations.com" IN {
    type master;
    file "benmorgancreations.com.zone";
    allow-update { none; };
    };

    zone "155.100.198.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "benmorgancreations.com.rr.zone";

    };
```

**In file: benmorgancreations.com.zone:**

```
$ORIGIN benmorgancreations.com. 
$TTL 86400 
@   IN  SOA dns1.benmorgancreations.com. webmaster.benmorgancreations.com. (
            2001062501 ; serial                     
            21600      ; refresh after 6 hours                     
            3600       ; retry after 1 hour                     
            604800     ; expire after 1 week                     
            86400 )    ; minimum TTL of 1 day


    IN  NS  ns1.benmorgancreations.com.       
    IN  NS  ns2.benmorgancreations.com.        


    IN  MX  10  mail.benmorgancreations.com.             


ns1 IN  A   198.100.155.226
ns2 IN  A   198.100.155.226
ftp IN  A   198.100.155.226
mail    IN  A   198.100.155.226
mail2   IN  A   198.100.155.226
```

**In my benmorgancreations.com.rr.zone**

```
$ORIGIN 155.100.198.in-addr.arpa. 
$TTL 86400

@   IN  SOA dns1.benmorgancreations.com.    webmaster.benmorgancreations.com. (

2001062501 ; serial                     
            21600      ; refresh after 6 hours                    
            3600       ; retry after 1 hour                     
            604800     ; expire after 1 week                     
            86400 )    ; minimum TTL of 1 day  

IN NS   ns1.benmorgancreations.com.       
IN NS   ns2.benmorgancreations.com.
226 IN  PTR    server1.benmorgancreations.com.
226 IN  PTR    server2.benmorgancreations.com.
226 IN  PTR    ftp.benmorgancreations.com.
226 IN  PTR    ftp.benmorgancreations.com.
```

**And in my 155.100.198.in-addr-arpa file:**

```
$TTL    86400 
@   IN  SOA benmorgancreations.com. webmaster.benmorgancreations.com.
(
            1441588071  ; Serial
            10800   ; Refresh
            3600    ; Retry
            604800  ; Expire
            10800   ; Minimum
            )


    IN  NS ns1.benmorgancreations.com.
    IN  NS ns2.benmorgancreations.com.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the config excerpt it's not clear that the *file* `155.100.198.in-addr.arpa` (`155.100.198.in-addr-arpa`?) is used at all.

The *zone* `155.100.198.in-addr.arpa`, however, has been set up to use the *file* `benmorgancreations.com.rr.zone` (a less than intuitive name) and that's where there appears to be a problem with the zone data.

As the error message implies, there are no `NS` records at the apex of your `155.100.198.in-addr.arpa` zone.

The problem here would appear to be a difference in whitespace between this zone and your working examples.

Specifically:

```
 IN NS   ns1.benmorgancreations.com.
```

and

```
IN NS   ns1.benmorgancreations.com.
```

will mean entirely different things when parsed.

First example:

Owner name (mandatory field): [blank] (inherits the owner name from previous record, `155.100.198.in-addr.arpa.`)
TTL (optional field): [not specified] (`86400` based on `$TTL`)
Class (optional field): `IN`
Type (mandatory field): `NS`
Data (mandatory field): `ns1.benmorgancreations.com.`

```
155.100.198.in-addr.arpa. 86400 IN NS ns1.benmorgancreations.com.
```

Second example:

Owner name (mandatory field): `IN`
TTL (optional field): [not specified] (`86400` based on `$TTL`)
Class (optional field): [not specified] (default class value `IN`)
Type (mandatory field): `NS`
Data (mandatory field): `ns1.benmorgancreations.com.`

```
IN.155.100.198.in-addr.arpa. 86400 IN NS ns1.benmorgancreations.com.
```

And, in the end what the error message is all about is that there are no `NS` records at `155.100.198.in-addr.arpa`.

Then, leaving the interesting part of the question behind.
Is the `198.100.155.0/24` IP network actually all yours? Ie, will `155.100.198.in-addr.arpa` actually be delegated to you so that people will query your nameservers for this zone?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, the IP is mine, as it is on a VPN. I've never had to work with zone files before, so this was very new to me. The white space issue makes sense. Thanks again for looking at it and for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, as indicated, in your zonefile:

```
$ORIGIN 155.100.198.in-addr.arpa. 
$TTL 86400
@   IN  SOA dns1.benmorgancreations.com.    webmaster.benmorgancreations.com. (
2001062501 ; serial                     
            21600      ; refresh after 6 hours                    
            3600       ; retry after 1 hour                     
            604800     ; expire after 1 week                     
            86400 )    ; minimum TTL of 1 day  

IN NS   ns1.benmorgancreations.com.       
IN NS   ns2.benmorgancreations.com.
```

In DNS short-hand a line starting with a whitespace is a continuation of the previous record.
That white-space is missing from the `IN NS` records which is why those don't register as NS records (but as an incorrect resource record for a host called called 'IN').

Simple add the leading white spaces, or the <kbd>@</kbd> shorthand for the zone ORIGIN.

```
@   IN NS   ns1.benmorgancreations.com.       
    IN NS   ns2.benmorgancreations.com.
```

Comment: In fairness, that might, or might not, be my fault.  The original post was so badly marked up that I may have introduced that corruption when trying to set it properly.  Really, the OP needs to come back, learn how to use the SE markup language, and properly insert his/her zonefiles.

Comment: That would be consistent with the error message though: `has no NS records`

Comment: Absolutely, I entirely agree.  I just thought it worth noting that people *might* be proceeding on false information.  Hopefully not.

Comment: Thanks HBruijn for the comment. I appreciate you taking the time and explaining the white space issue.

Comment: @MadHatter, I agree I don't know much about the markup language, which is why I posted it here. I appreciate you modifying my question to make it more readable.